# Problems Oauth 2 and Google APIs in appmobi

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-oauth, appmobi

After a lot of work I managed to make a simple Oauth authentication work for Twitter API, however, my intention was to be sure the basics were working to implement a Google APIs authentication.

The thing is that if I try to create a Service in the same why I did for Twitter Im unable to find the urls that I need (RequestTokenEndpoint, AuthorizeEndpoint, AccessTokenEndpoint). In the Twitter dev portal its really easy to find, but its not at google's.

Anyway if you go to https://developers.google.com/accounts/ ... stalledApp, they provide you a url to make requests. IE

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&client_id=812741506391-h38jh0j4fv0ce1krdkiq0hfvt6n5amrf.apps.googleusercontent.com

And this url contains all you need to open the authentication window. I also tried the showRemoteSiteExt for this url but you are not able to open it (google restrictions).

So, could anyone explain me how can I proceed to sucess in Google Api authentication? I have read the Twitter and facebook examples, but Google case is different.

In this site you can find all the fields that I need:

http://www.html5dev-software.intel.com/documentation/content/Articles/Article_UsingOAuth/index.html?r=6033

Request Token Endpoint

Authorize Endpoint

Access Token Endpoint

And the one to get the authorization. If you do the same in twitter they provide all the fields you need, but not in google apis.

Any help?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like appmobi is not supporting oauth 2, and the google api I'm trying to use tells me to use oauth 2. I think I'll move to phonegap or native development.
Thanks